Python SetupTools - Exclude package
I've started working with setuptools in Python and I'm facing strange issue. I'm trying to exclude tests, but whatever I'm trying is not working.
Here's my project structure:
awesome-app/
├── src/
│   ├── components
│   ├── models
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── run.py
├── tests/
└── setup.py
    

And setup.py content:
import setuptools
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setuptools.setup(
    name="awesome-app",
    version="1.0.0",
    package_dir=find_packages(exclude=["tests"]),
    package_data={"": ["*.json"]},
    entry_points="src"
)

What's I'm running is python -m build --sdist

have you tried removing *.egg-info and build dir. And building again after that?

Have you tried exclude=["tests/"]?

Tried exclude=["tests/"] and didn't work. While building there are two foulders created, awesome-app and dist. I'm removing them both before rerunning.
